# Indentation error after if statement condition

Tags: python-2.7, indentation

in the following code, there is indentation error at line 5.
what i want is when if condition at line 4 is true then break 
should execute otherwise div=div+2 should execute.

```
max_num=input()
for num in range(2,max_num+1):
 for div in range(3,max_num/2):
   if(num%div==0):break
   div=div+2 
 else: print num
 if(num==2): num=num+1
 else      : num=num+2
```

I am new with python. please help me out.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Please use 2 or 4 spaces for indentation. I see your indentation is inconsistent - one time you use 1 space and the others you use 3.

What you did **should** work as I see, but it's just inconsistent.

Here is a slightly more organized version:

```
max_num=input()

for num in range(2,max_num+1):
    for div in range(3,max_num/2):
        if(num%div==0): break
        div=div+2 
    else:
        print num

    if(num==2):
        num=num+1
    else:
        num=num+2
```

You can also optimize it to work more efficiently like so:

```
# Makes sure only ints are allowed. Else throws an exception
max_num = int(raw_input())

for num in range(2, max_num + 1):
    try:
        (div for div in range(3, max_num / 2, 2) if num % div == 0).next()
    except StopIteration:
        print num

    # This section is not used as I see
    # if(num==2):
    #     num=num+1
    # else:
    #     num=num+2
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest add this code, but i would want to know what is the wanted result for yor code.

```
max_num=input()
for num in range(2,max_num+1):
 for div in range(3,max_num/2):
   if(num%div==0):break
   else:div=div+2 
 print num
 if(num==2): num=num+1
 else      : num=num+2
```